# Drupal Views Table with Alternating Amount of Columns

Tags: 7, views, theming

I'm trying to make a view with alternating amount of columns. The first row should have only 1 column, while the second row needs 2 colums, third 1 column and fourth again 2 coulumns. The fields displayed are the titles of a certain content type.

I want to be able to use a table or a grid if possible.

Currently I'm using an unformatted list and used css to display it the way I want, but then it's no longer quite responsive.

What should I do?

ex.

title 1

title 2 I title 3

title 4

title 5 I title 6

Comment: If you want it to be responsive (by which I assume you mean it will display well on different devices) then a table will almost certainly be worse for that. Can you explain in what way it is not responsive now?

Comment: I work with a 12 column grid and was able to give the class col-md-6 to title 2 I title 3 and title 5 I title 6. Which works well, as long as my screen size doesn't change.

Overall it works alright, but it just seems like a messy solution to me right now and I was wondering if there was a cleaner idea than using pure css to get what I want :)

Comment: Compared to any of the alternatives, using CSS and a responsive grid is likely to be the cleanest solution. Given that the layout you are working with is not a common case, you will almost certainly have to tweak the CSS for different break points. There's not going to be anything that just works.

Comment: Where you able to find a solution for this? I would really like to see an answer posted for this problem. I am also use the Bootstrap framework and wondering how you did this.